# Can't find program entry point in a C++ project

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, program-entry-point, pipeline, entry-point

I have a C++ project in Ubuntu 12.04. To run the project the make file requires the following files:

1-All the .cpp files

2-All the .h files

3-Three shared libraries.

The project is fully functionall and performs according to the specifications. All the required .cpp files and .h files are available. The problem is that there is no main() function in any of the source files and the program entry point resides in one of the three shared libraries. My job is to find out the program execution pipeline and without having any main file I am not able to do that. I can't run the project in any IDE (i.e: eclipse) because there is no main function available.

**Question: Can you please tell me how to find the program entry point?**

P.S: I will be glad to provide any kind of information or material you may need to solve my problem.

**Edit**: The CMakeLists.txt file available [here](http://txt.do/tsu3).

**Edit 2**: The build.sh file available [here](http://txt.do/tsfw).

Comment: You can't have an executable without `main`. Expand the search a bit, maybe. Try some `grep -RIi main *` or something like this in the project's main dir.

Comment: You could try `nm` on the shared libraries and see if they have a main. Also, could it be that a header has a macro that expands to `main`? Did you look for `main` in the headers too?

Comment: @KirilKirov Believe me I have check every file in the project manually and with grep.

Comment: @VisaisRacism Yes indeed I did. I check all the source files, .cpp and .h files.

Comment: @Zindarod - OK, if there's nothing in the source/header files, check what object files or libraries are used in the `makefile`, the `main` may be in some other place(not sure if possible, but I don't see a reason not to be). For dynamic libs, `ldd executable` could be useful (lists all dynamic libraries, used by the executable).

Comment: @KirilKirov I have the list of all the .so files needed for the project. The problem is I don't know how to search the main() in them.

Comment: Attach a debugger and walk up the callstack until you find main?

Comment: @JoeGauterin Did an nm and found the main in one of the .so files. Now have to find a way to decompile the .so file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find enty point look into each shared object with:

```
nm $library | egrep "T main$"
```

Library with `main()` will output something like

```
090d8ab0 T main
```

---

Very usefull way to visualize execution tree is to run:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./my_executable -arg -arg ....
```

*(you can abort execution early with **Ctrl+C**)*

This will output `callgrind.<pid>` file. To visualize it run `kcachegrind callgrind.<pid>`.

---

You will need **valgrind**:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

and **kcachegrind**

```
sudo apt-get install kcachegrind
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already found the shared object containing the main(). Now the problem is how to find the execution pipeline from the main(). I will try your suggestion and let you know of the results.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting **valgrind**. I may not get the original main() code back but this is the closest thing without the need for disassembling the machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Build it with the debug option `-g` and step into the program with a debugger like gdb (or cgdb or ddd). You'll need any appropriate debug libraries libraries though.

Short of that, play with the code a bit. Try putting `printf` or `cout` statements that print internal variables in any functions that look important, and see what the program status is and how frequently they get called. If `main` is hidden in a library, there's probably another function somewhere that behaves like `main` for the purposes of the API provided by whatever library has the real `main`.

What's the API documentation for your  libraries? (is this a school project?). It sounds odd to have a hidden `main` and not say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use a build system (CMake, SCons, ...) it is highly possible that the build system is also generating some files, and one of them might be containing the `main()` method. We use this methodology when we generate the main function in order to instantiate classes for libraries that were specifically selected in CMake-gui.

And again, it is possible that the build system deletes the generated files due to some obscure policy the original developers thought of but didn't tell you. So search through your build system files, see what is actually happening there.

**Edit**

So, after seeing you CMakeLists.txt:

check `${DIR_EXT}/covis/src/ci.cpp` where `DIR_EXT` is `SET( DIR_EXT "../ext/" CACHE PATH "Folder holding external libraries" )`

See what's in there and let us know :)

**Edit2**

After seeing `build.sh` (execute steps in order):

**1.**
change

```
`cmake -D COMPILE_BINARY=ON ..`
```

to

```
`cmake -D COMPILE_BINARY=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`
```

and add the same `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to the other `cmake` command too.

This will build your library and executable in debug mode.

**2.**
Now, in one of the c++ source files you have access to and you are sure will be called (the earlier the function will be calle the better), add:

```
asm("int $0x03");
```

This will create a breakpoint in your application.

(If you do not want to use this, see below).

**3.**
Build your application.

**4.**
Run it via a debugger in terminal:

```
gdb ./myapplication <ENTER>
```

(this will give you a gdb prompt)

(if you did not add the `asm` breakpoint from above, type in the gdb prompt: `break filename.cpp:linenumber` or `break methodname` to add a gdb breakpoint).

```
run <ENTER>
```

Now your application should stop in your function when it is executed.
You are still in the gdb prompt, so type:

```
bt <ENTER>
```

This will print out the backtrace of your application. Somewhere you should see a main function, together with filename and linenumber.

However, that `setnames.sh` looks interesting, see if it does not do anything funny :)

Comment: I did an nm on one of the .so files and found the main there. Now the problem is that generating C/C++ code from assembly code is very difficult and not always readable. Now my problem is find some way to decompile the so file.

Comment: Noo, do not decompile it. How do you build?

Comment: I have build.sh file which runs the CMakeList file.

Comment: Fine. Look through the CMakeLists.txt files and see if there are any file operations creating files, writing to files, such as `configure_file`, or `file(write,`, `file(append` (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:file) Or post the CMakeLists.txt somewhere... maybe update the question.

Comment: Please check the above edit for the CMakeLists.txt file link.

Comment: The **ci.cpp** file is an empty file.

Comment: What??? That's amazing :) Can you recompile the app with debug info in it? Also can you show the `build.sh`?

Comment: I have only debugged projects running on an IDE (i.e: eclipse, VS). This project is built and run on terminal.

Comment: Nevermind, it's easy. Can you edit the source of the application?

Comment: Please check the above edit for build.sh and yes I can edit the source files.

Comment: @Zindarod check the edits :) Also, if it is not working show the `setnames.sh`

Comment: setnames.sh http://txt.do/tspt. Although I am able to build and run the project without the setnames.sh file too.

Comment: @Zindarod ok, setnames does not look interesting for this purpose. Did you try the debugging?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the point of debugging. The function I put the breakpoint is the one I know for sure will get executed. I have put print commands in that function previously to check.

Comment: when you debug you get a "stack trace" which shows you all the way up to main, together with filename and linenumbers.

Comment: Please see GreenScape's answer. I have successfully gotten a visualization of the stack trace with valgrind. Thank you for your time and effort. :)

Comment: I'm happy you found a solution!